# Configuration class not found for WebLogic local standalone with cargo maven plugin

Tags: java, maven-2, weblogic, cargo, maven-cargo

I recently discovered Cargo and am really excited about its potential for allowing developers to consistently and automatically test web artifacts using maven -- but I am having trouble getting it configured correctly.  For better or worse, we are a WebLogic shop, but I have been unable to find a good example of configuring a WebLogic Local Standalone using Cargo's Maven plugin, as the plugin is unable to find the org.codehaus.cargo.container.weblogic.WebLogic103xStandaloneLocalConfiguration class.

To simplify things, I started with the archetype (which includes samples for ever server EXCEPT weblogic....gee thanks) and changed the plugin under pluginManagement to look like this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <container>
                <containerId>weblogic103x</containerId>
                <type>standalone</type>
                <home>${weblogic.10.3.server}</home>
            </container>
            <configuration>
                <type>local</type>
                <properties>
                    <cargo.servlet.port>8001</cargo.servlet.port>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Some of this may be redundant (I'm not very experienced with maven profiles), but I also added an additional profile and made it default:

```
<profile>
  <id>weblogic103x</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>weblogic103x</containerId>
                    <type>standalone</type>
                    <home>${weblogic.10.3.server}</home>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <type>local</type>
                    <implementation>org.codehaus.cargo.container.weblogic.WebLogic103xStandaloneLocalConfiguration</implementation>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.servlet.port>8001</cargo.servlet.port>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</profile>
```

And the exception I get is:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Custom configuration implementation [org.codehaus.cargo.container.weblogic.WebLogic103xStandaloneLocalConfiguration] cannot be loaded
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Custom configuration implementation [org.codehaus.cargo.container.weblogic.WebLogic103xStandaloneLocalConfiguration] cannot be loaded
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        [snip]... several more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Custom configuration implementation [org.codehaus.cargo.container.weblogic.WebLogic103xStandaloneLocalConfiguration] cannot be loaded
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.configuration.Configuration.createConfiguration(Configuration.java:266)
        [snip]... several more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.cargo.container.weblogic.WebLogic103xStandaloneLocalConfiguration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.configuration.Configuration.createConfiguration(Configuration.java:259)
        ... 24 more
```

Am I just missing some setting?  Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding how Cargo is supposed to work?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it.  This was occurring because I had specified an implementation class in the profile.  Once that was removed, the error was:

```
There's no registered configuration for the parameters (container [id = [weblogic103x], type = [standalone]], configuration type [local]).
```

This is of course because I needed to pay closer attention to **exactly** the which values are allowed which type field -- Container type vs Configuration type.  This page has the reference:

http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+Plugin+Reference+Guide

Once I got the container type to "installed" and the configuration type to "standalone", things went much more smoothly.

So, RTFM on me!  :)